# How to call An Animation Function from another class in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, function

I have code for slide animation written in **first** class

```
-(void)send 
{

        right=[[ViewProfileRightPanel alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewProfileRightPanel" bundle:Nil];

        right.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 260, 548);

        [self.view showOrigamiTransitionWith:right.view
                               NumberOfFolds:[@"1" intValue]
                                    Duration:[@"0.58" floatValue]

                                   Direction:currDirectionRightPanel
                                  completion:^(BOOL finished) { NSLog(@"4");

                                  }];


    }
```

This code is called when I press button in **first** class and it will open the right panel. Animation to close the right panel is,

```
-(void)close
{
 [self.view hideOrigamiTransitionWith:right.view
                                   NumberOfFolds:[@"1" intValue]
                                        Duration:[@"0.58" floatValue]

                                       Direction:currDirectionRightPanel
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                      }];
}
```

Now I want to perform the close animation on press of button in **second** class instead of pressing button from **first** class.

**Question**: How can I access the function of **first** class from **second** class?

Comment: make it class method and access it with  class name wherever you want :)

Comment: You can improve your code vastly by writing `1` instead of `[@"1" intValue]` or `0.58` instead of `[@"0.58" floatValue]`. It's correct, has the same result, is shorter, nicer to read and avoids creating a string that needs to be parsed.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you define protocol (delegate) in your firstClass which has the function (void)close and then include that protocol as a property in your second class and access the function from the second class via this property.

Comment: how to do it i created delegate but it is not working

Comment: [HERE](http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html) is a good basic introduction to delegates in iOS and how to use them.